# Runtime error 13 handling - continue For Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA for Loop, and occasionally are getting a Runtime Error 13 which I want to handle by increment i.

I have attempted to handle the error but it still throws Runtime error 13.

```
For i = 2 To lastRow
    On Error GoTo stringNotFound
    strString = (ws.Cells(i, 2).Value) 'get value of cell
    ' Do other stuff
    stringNotFound:
Next i
```

How do I handle it so that in the event of a error the cell is skipped and i is incremented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For i = 2 To lastRow
    If IsError(ws.Cells(i, 2)) = False Then
        strString = (ws.Cells(i, 2).Value)    'get value of cell
        ' Do other stuff
    End If
Next i
```